# How I can access to array element outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, frontend

I want to access  `distance` and `pos` element  outside from function. How  can I do this ?

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
    //   console.log(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(pos.lat, pos.lng, feature.position.lat(), feature.position.lng()));
    distance.push({
        dis: getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(pos.lat, pos.lng, feature.position.lat(), feature.position.lng()),
        lat: feature.position.lat(),
        lng: feature.position.lng()
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your variables outside the function if the function is just used as a setter.

```
    var pos, distance;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        distance.push({
            dis: getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(pos.lat, pos.lng, feature.position.lat(), feature.position.lng()),
            lat: feature.position.lat(),
            lng: feature.position.lng()
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're passing an inline function for this, but maybe there's a reason?

In order to access distance and pos from outside the function, you need to [return](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp) them. If you want to return more than one variable (like in your case), I would probably create an object and return the object:

```
return { pos: pos, distance: distance };
```

Outside of the function you would access it as object.pos / object.distance

Comment: _Not sure why you're passing an inline function for this_ [getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) needs one